# Do not show alert each time when startUpdatelocation

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

I am working on location app where I need to get the location. When I come on the particular ViewController & location is off it gives alert showing that switch on the location which is fine.But the problem is once I say cancel  & next time call `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` it will not show me alert to switch on location.

```
  - (void)getCurrentLocation {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

        if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {

            [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }

        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }
```

> Note - I have done changes in plist to
>   NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription set to The XYZ app would like to use
>   your current location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is by design. Its so an app developer can't harass the user with endless requests.

What you have to do is check the `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` and if its `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` then display a message that the user needs to go into their settings app and enable locations for your app.

You should handle the other authorized states as well. See the list in the [CLLocationManager Documentation - CLAuthorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@CLAuthorizationStatus)

Answer (score 1):

Check the status before startUpdatingLocation. i.e.

```
          if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
             {
                if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
                    NSLog(@"Add your alert here");
                }
                else
                {
                    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Add your alert here");
            }
```

Comment: Thank You Minkle it will add to davids point. +1 for helping.